# Polymorphic Request-Response in EasyNetQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I was wondering whether I could do polymorphic request-response in EasyNetQ, in a way similar to [polymorphic publish-subscribe](https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/wiki/Polymorphic-Publish-and-Subscribe)

Here is an example that uses Mike Hadlow's example with `Cat`s and `Dog`s (check the link above) but with `Animal` being a class instead of an interface. I am trying to do something like:

```
Animal d = new Dog();
bus.Request<Animal, string>(d);
```

If on the receiving end I have the following,

```
bus.Respond<Dog, string>(...);
```

the request is never captured by the responder as it is sent as `Animal` instead of `Dog`.

The point here is that the request doesn't really care what it's sending (apart from the fact that it's sending an `Animal`) and the input comes from different parts of the system so I can't know the exact type in advance. There will be different listeners to respond to different subclasses (one listener for `Dog` and another one for `Cat`), so I can't just listen on `Animal` requests. `TResponse` is going to be the same regardless of `TRequest`.

Is there a way to do something equivalent to the polymorphic publish-subscribe? For example, something like:

```
bus.Request<string>(d.getType(), d);
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT**: More info:

currently in my codebase I use the (extension) method `bus.Publish(msg.GetType(), msg);` in order to properly route the message to the correct listener based on the instance type of `msg` which I only know at runtime. This allows me to avoid code duplication like `bus.Publish<Dog>(msg)`, `bus.Publish<Cat>(msg);` by providing the same function call (no code flow branches) as a way to publish different types of messages. I wanted to use a non-generic `bus.Request()` method too, and use it like `bus.Request(msg.GetType(), string.GetType(), msg)`, to avoid calling this method multiple times like in `bus.Request<Dog, string>(msg)`, `bus.Request<Cat, string>(msg);`. Hopefully I could avoid doing this: [calling generic method at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455977/calling-a-generic-function-with-a-type-parameter-determined-at-runtime).

Answer (score 1):

The routing is by the combination of TRequest, TResponse, so you have to make sure they are the same on both the requester and the responder. Any subtype combination of TRequest, TResponse should serialise correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using the dynamic keyword; before publishing the command.

```
  public void MethodName(IAnimal animal)
    {
        dynamic actualObject = animal;
        bus.Publish(actualObject);
    }
```