# c# .Net Core DI: Request from ServiceProvider a implementation of a generic interface where the generic property is only known at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

I have following issue: 
I'm working on a system which processes various Types of "Events" which all trigger a different business logic (called EventProcessor in this example). The code is now refactored to a point where I now want one generic "Eventprocessor" which is able to, dependent on the ingested event type, returns the correct Businesslogic to process this event.

```
    public class GenericEventProcessor
    {
        private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; }

        public GenericEventProcessor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this._serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public Task RunAsync(string eventCarrierString, ILogger log, string functionName)
        {
            var eventCarrier = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventCarrier>(eventCarrierString);

            Type eventType= typeof(eventCarrier.EventType);

            var eventProcessor =_serviceProvider.GetService(IEventProcessor<eventType>)

            eventProcessor.RunAsync(eventCarrier.eventString, log, functionName)
        }
    }
```

The event is passed in as a "EventCarrier" Object which has two properties, 
-A Enum telling which type of Event this is,
-And another string which contains the actual event.

The actual business logic is implemented in various EventProcessors which implement a IEventProcessor Interface, where T is some Event.

This apparently does not work (because i can't pass the eventType into the Generic Interface) and i have the feeling that i'm doing this completly wrong.

What would you suggest to implement something like this? (Or get this to run!)

Thanks in advance,
Matthias

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a generic function with a type parameter determined at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455977/calling-a-generic-function-with-a-type-parameter-determined-at-runtime)

Comment: are you trying to invoke `GetService<T>()` or `GetService(Type)` ?

Comment: Rephrased the title a bit. @Xiaoy312 I try to invoke GetService<T>().

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [MakeGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=netframework-4.8) to build required type at runtime

```
Type eventType= typeof(eventCarrier.EventType);
            Type processor  = typeof(IEventProcessor<>);
             Type generic = processor.MakeGenericType(eventType);
        var eventProcessor =_serviceProvider.GetService(generic);
```